# Locating on of the specific elements

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, webdriver

I want to locate one of the specific elements on webpage. How to use
 `find_element_by_partial_link_text` to find out one of the following text "xxx" or "yyy"?

Example:

I need to find out one of "selenium" and "webdriver".

Using one command instead of following two:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("selenium")
```

or

```
element = driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("webdriver")
```

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=webdriver

[image]

I try `element = driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text(["selenium","webdriver"])`, but fail.

Comment: Your  questions is unclear. Provide complete detail . And specific problem you are facing

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this in Google page , it is just a demo

```
driver = driver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/?gws_rd=ssl")
element = driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("Gmail")
```